# How to configure Eclipse automatic static imports to prefer MatcherAssert.assertThat over Assert.assertThat?

Tags: eclipse, junit, junit4, hamcrest

We recently upgraded to JUnit 4.13 and my project was painted warning yellow because `Assert.assertThat` has now been deprecated in favour of `MatcherAssert.assertThat`.

Bulk changing my static imports is no big deal but I was hoping that going forward I could configure Eclipse to do the right thing in new code. But no matter what I do, the auto importer continues to pull in the deprecated `Assert.assertThat` instead of the `MatcherAssert` one.

Some things I've tried:

- Add `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*` to **Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites**. Now I see `MatcherAssert.assertThat` as a quick fix suggestion when there is no import and I mouse over the code.  But this doesn't affect the automatic imports at all.

  [image]
- Add `org.junit.Assert.assertThat` to **Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters**.  (I've also tried `org.junit.Assert.*` and even `org.junit.*`)  This seems to have no effect on static imports.  I can see the setting taking effect on regular imports when I experimented with `org.junit.*` but nothing on static imports.

So no matter what I do, when I hit save without explicitly pulling in `MatcherAssert.assertThat`, the auto import pulls `Assert.assertThat` instead.

Do you know if there is some way around this?

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine did some super sleuthing and discovered that as of Eclipse 2020-09, the Content Assist Favorites now influences automatic static imports:

[Bug 283287 - [organize imports] Could use favorites for static imports](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283287)

And since the Favorites configuration lets you specify specific class members, I was able to get around this problem by adding `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*` and then changing my previous `org.junit.Assert.*` to a more specific set including all of the public members of that class except for `assertThat`.

In the end, I have something like this, which does the right thing both in the automatic imports and in the content assist quick-fix suggestions.

[image]

Comment: So you were at least two releases behind?

Comment: No, I was up to date, but everything I read online about how to configure the automatic "organize imports" talked about using the Type Filters and implied that the Content Assist Favourites only influence the content assist pop-ups.  So I didn't even try this approach originally.